# Replace a img using only CSS and cannot change HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a project that has 2 different CSS, one light and one dark. And a few images are inside the `<img>` tag, and I need to change their colors, only using css, since I'M NOT ALLOWED TO CHANGE HTML OR JAVASCRIPT

So, I thought on using their ID to overlap them.
I actually got the image to be on the same place, however, behind the original image.

Any ideas?

The HTML

```
<div id="div-icones" style="width: 164px;">

<ul id="ulIcones" class="icones">
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="" title="Trocar para a versão simplificada" onclick="ChangeVersionHB('min');">
            <img title="Trocar para a versão simplificada" id="imgChangeVersion" src="images/ico_hb_min.png" width="16" height="16">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="" title="Salvar Configuração" onclick="saveCfg();">
            <img title="Salvar Configuração" id="imgSave" src="images/ico_sv.png" width="16" height="16">
            </a>
        </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="" title="Restaurar Configuração Padrão" onclick="resetCfgDefault();">
            <img title="Restaurar Configuração Padrão" id="imgConfDefault" src="images/folder_image.png" width="16" height="16">
            </a>
        </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="" title="Bloquear funções de Layout" onclick="oSTBroker.fixLayout();">
            <img title="Bloquear funções de Layout" id="imgCadeado" src="images/lock_open.png" width="16" height="16">
            </a>
        </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="" title="Configuração do Cliente" onclick="showCfgCli();">
        <img title="Configuração do Cliente" id="imgCliCfg" src="images/ico_cg.png" width="16" height="16">
            </a>
        </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="" title="Teclas de Atalho" onclick="showHotkeys();">
        <img title="Teclas de Atalho" id="imgHotkeys" src="images/ico_hk.png" width="16" height="16">
            </a>
        </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="" title="Manual" onclick="AbrePagina(ConfigHB.urlManual, 'WINmn', '', 'no', 'yes', '780', '560', false);">
        <img title="Manual" id="imgAjuda" src="images/ico_aj.png" width="16" height="16">
            </a>
        </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="" title="Seleciona CSS" onclick="AbrePagina('LstEstilos.aspx', 'LstEstilos', '', 'no', 'yes', '780', '300', false);">
            <img title="Selecione o layout" id="imgSelCss" src="images/ico_ml.png" width="16" height="16">
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My CSS to change the image

```
#imgChangeVersion {

box-sizing: border-box;
background: url(images/ico_hb_minc.png);
background-size: 16px;

}
```

Comment: why not just hide the image and put the background image in the anchor?

Comment: I cant't change the HTML, It must be done using only CSS

Comment: #imgChangeVersion is one image, #imgSave in another image thet I have to do the same

Comment: @BrunoDeFaria What epascarello says is right... You can do that. Give a `display: none` to the `<img />` and use `background-image` for the `<a>` along with `width` and `height`.

Comment: I understand, however, I need to change six more images, if I display: none to the </img> I loose all the different ID's, and all the images will be tha same, since my <a> does not have any ID's or classes.

Comment: Can you post your other HTML, as you said you have six more images?

Comment: is this some kind of coding challenge? If not, just tell your client you need to use javascript or change the html.

Comment: @Stickers just added the HTML

Comment: At least you have different titles on a tags, use `a[title="Seleciona CSS"]` and `a[title="Seleciona CSS"] img` as selectors.

Comment: @Jasonbamber cannot do it, it's a complicated project, very restricted and controlled, to change on line of HTML it is needed to change many bases on various servers, the html is created dynamically.

Comment: @Stickers didn't even know that was possible. I used it, but when I display none on the img, the change from a[title="Seleciona CSS"] also goes away.

Comment: I didn't go away, simply because it will be like empty in <a>, use visibility:hidden rather than display:none, or give <a> some size.

Comment: @Stickers CONGRATS, it worked, Thanks a lot!!!! You made my week!!!

Comment: @Stickers you should post it as an answer

Comment: @Stickers yes, I'm not sure how to do it here, I'm kinf of new here, not sure how to proceed.

Comment: You're good. I posted an answer, feel free to accept or comment if you have more questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you cannot have pseudo elements with `<img>` tag (although it might work in some browsers, but it's certainly non-standard). So you'll have to use parent selectors if they have unique classes, ids or attributes.

In your example, all the `<a>` have different `title` values. So you can do:

```
a[title="Trocar para a versão simplificada"] {...}
a[title="Trocar para a versão simplificada"] img {...}

a[title="Salvar Configuração"] {...}
a[title="Salvar Configuração"] img {...}
```

You can hide the `img` by applying `display:none` (collapse) or `visibility:hidden` (keep space).

Then apply background image on each `a` tag, you probably also want to set it to `display:block` or `inline-block` and give it some `width` and `height`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the "content" property, like so:

```
#imgChangeVersion {
box-sizing: border-box;
content:url(images/image.png); /* change image here */
background-size: 16px;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/49s5zj7p/10/)**

Comment: It didn´t work, I olmost got it with with background image and setting background size, the image goses behind the original.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should use the solution that was described in some of the comments on the initial question along with css selectors like nth-of-type() or nth-child() since your `<a>` tags don't have classes.

```
img {
   display: none;
}
a:nth-of-type(){
   background-image: url('');
   width: 16px;
   height: 16px;
}
```

Read up on the [nth-of-type selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp) and [nth-child selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

Also consider using `+` selector to target `<a>` elements immediately within `<li>` elements such as:

```
li + a:nth-of-type(){
    background-image: url('');
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}
```

In both of these solutions make sure to put a number inbetween the parentheses following nth-of-type, i.e. `nth-of-type(3)` to target the 3rd element.

Comment: I'll try, I just need to study a bit of how to use the nth, I've never used it before.

Comment: nth-of-type will apply to all <a> tags on the page, so you might consider using something like the + selector to target <a> tags directly in <li> tags. I edited my answer to include a note about this.

Comment: Thanks @Tim Willis, I'll check more about that.